# What Applications Use MEF

Tags: .net, mef

Does anyone know of any applications that are currently using MEF? I'm looking for a good program to derive some idea on using MEF and seeing how others are using it will help me out a lot -- obviously this means open source programs would be favored.

Comment: Quick google for "mef demos" brought up a [silverlight-based example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joen/archive/2010/01/24/great-demo-of-mef.aspx). Looking for something specific?

Comment: Maybe something w/ winforms.

Comment: Can't help on the open source front, but I use MEF a lot in our commercial products. Self-assembling data processing pipelines composed of optional modules, etc.

Comment: I'm looking at implementing plug-in functionality with MEF. My understanding is that is partially what this platform is designed to do...I was curious about having forms built-in to the plugins so that they could generate additional UI components for use without the main application having to know much about those.

Comment: Yes! Absolutely. MEF is designed to bring in things that you don't know about at the time you build your application (i.e. plugins). [Here is a SO post that talks a little about it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216565/why-exactly-isnt-mef-a-di-ioc-container)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Visual Studio itself uses MEF for editor extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885122.aspx) you could look into how some of these are written.

Also there is a project developed by [Microsoft Patterns and Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921345.aspx) that is called [Prism](https://compositewpf.codeplex.com/), which can use [MEF for its DI](http://archfirst.org/books/getting-started-prism-and-mef). It is set up to be used with WPF, but as Glenn Block shows [here](http://codebetter.com/glennblock/2008/10/20/bringing-prism-to-winforms/) it can be used with WinForms as well.

I have used a variation of Prism with MEF on my projects before and have been satisfied with the results.